# Puppeteer is filtering out html values

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, web-crawler, puppeteer

Looks like puppeteer is removing the numbers `21` and `22` from the html.
I'm scrapping a page that contains the following HTML:

```html
<div class="roster__player">
  <a href="/atletas/225391">
    <div class="roster__player__info clearfix">
      <div class="roster__player__header">
        <h2 class="roster__player__header__heading">Andre Cruz</h2>
        <div class="roster__player__header_position">EXTREMO</div>
        <div class="roster__player__header_jnumber">
          21
          <div class="roster-fa-legend-dot">•</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="roster__player__bust-wrapper">
        <img class="roster__player__bust" src="https://sav2.fpb.pt/uploads/utilizadores/153455_1695740510.png" alt="Andre Cruz">
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="roster__player">
  <a href="/atletas/130949">
    <div class="roster__player__info clearfix">
      <div class="roster__player__header">
        <h2 class="roster__player__header__heading">Arnette Hallman</h2>
        <div class="roster__player__header_position">EXTREMO /  POSTE</div>
        <div class="roster__player__header_jnumber">
          22
          <div class="roster-fa-legend-dot">•</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="roster__player__bust-wrapper">
        <img class="roster__player__bust" src="https://sav2.fpb.pt/uploads/utilizadores/51458_1695740545.png" alt="Arnette Hallman">
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

My initial goal is to extract "Andre Cruz", "Extremo", the number "21", etc from each player. But as I'm simply not able to extract 21 from the code.
Attempting to select `roster__player__header_jnumber` returns the "•" character and nothing else.

```js
page.evaluate(() => {
      const playerNodes = document.querySelectorAll('.roster__player');
      return Array.from(playerNodes).map((playerNode) => ({
        name: playerNode.querySelector('.roster__player__header__heading')
          ?.textContent?.trim(),
        position: playerNode.querySelector('.roster__player__header_position')
          ?.textContent?.trim(),
        number: playerNode.querySelector('.roster__player__header_jnumber')
          ?.textContent?.trim(),
        profileImage: playerNode.querySelector('.roster__player__bust')
          ?.getAttribute('src'),
        url: playerNode.querySelector('a')?.getAttribute('href'),
      }));
    });
```

I've even tried to extract the entire html secion as

```js
.querySelectorAll('.roster__player');
const test = Array.from(playerNodes)[0].innerHTML;
console.log(test);
```

And the number 21 just vanished:

```html
<a href="/atletas/95906">
  <div class="roster__player__info clearfix">
    <div class="roster__player__header">
      <h2 class="roster__player__header__heading">Andre Dara</h2>
      <div class="roster__player__header_position">BASE</div>
      <div class="roster__player__header_jnumber">
        <div class="roster-fa-legend-dot">•</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="roster__player__bust-wrapper">
      <img class="roster__player__bust" src="https://sav2.fpb.pt/uploads/utilizadores/26011_1667760476.png" alt="Andre Dara">
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

If you defined correct structure, my only guess that you are getting text too early (when it has not been rendered yet).

Try to wait for first element and only then perform `evaluate`.

Also, except `evaluate`, I suggest to use `$$eval`, it is shorter and actually does what you have done in first lines inside your arrow function.

I created a page your HTML for example and replaced `textContent` to `innerText` property:

```js
   const url =
      "https://inputnum.w3spaces.com/saved-from-Tryit-2023-10-11-qdk2k.html";
    await page.goto(url);

    await page.waitForSelector('.roster__player');
    const data = await page.$$eval('.roster__player', els => {
      return els.map((playerNode) => ({
        name: playerNode.querySelector('.roster__player__header__heading')
          ?.textContent?.trim(),
        position: playerNode.querySelector('.roster__player__header_position')
          ?.textContent?.trim(),
        number: playerNode.querySelector('.roster__player__header_jnumber')?.['innerText']?.split('\n')[0],
        profileImage: playerNode.querySelector('.roster__player__bust')
          ?.getAttribute('src'),
        url: playerNode.querySelector('a')?.getAttribute('href'),
      }));
    });
    console.log(data);
```